# How to iterate there a list with a formula?

Tags: python

I'm new to python and just started working on it. I need some help on my code. I can't get to produce the outcome I needed on my code. Tried many ways but still can't get it to work.

```
extra_hours = hours_worked - 40 
extra_rate = rate_of_pay * 1.5
pay_for_weeks = (rate_of_pay * 40) + (extra_rate * extra_hours)



rate_of_payy = [45,15,63,23,39]
total = []
for i in range (len(rate_of_payy)):
    pay_for_weeks = (rate_of_pay * 40) + (extra_rate * extra_hours)

    total.append(pay_for_weeks)
print(total)
```

Expected output:

```
Paying 475.0 by direct deposit
Paying 150.0 by mailed check
Paying 745.0 by direct deposit
Paying 230.0 by mailed check
Paying 390.0 by direct deposit
```

Comment: Could you add the missing variables to reproduce your problem - and, the output you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the print statement inside the loop, so you can print every element in each statement.

```py
print('Paying {} by {}'.format(amount, method)
```

The `format` method of a string allows you to interpolate variables inside an string in an elegant way. Take a look to this [guide](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/format).

The whole code would look something like follows. I also commented some misbehaviours and errors:

```py
extra_hours = hours_worked - 40 
extra_rate = rate_of_pay * 1.5
# This line is not necessary, you're computing it for each element inside the loop
# pay_for_weeks = (rate_of_pay * 40) + (extra_rate * extra_hours)

rate_of_pay = [45,15,63,23,39]
for r in rate_of_pay:
    # Iterating over length of a list gives it's indices, not it's values
    # pay_for_weeks = (rate_of_pay * 40) + (extra_rate * extra_hours)
    # Simply iterate directly over list elements
    pay_for_weeks = (r * 40) + (extra_rate * extra_hours)
    # Here obtain the payment method into a `method` variable.
    print('Paying {} by {}'.format(pay_for_weeks, method)
```

Comment: What is method?

Comment: Method is like a function. String is a class that has many functions (called methods) to operate to a string. You can call these methods by 'my_string'.methodname()

Comment: But this is a general topic of [OOP](https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/) not related specifically to this question, take a look to some tutorial if not familiar with it.